# Python2.7 - read a python file and then search for a dictionary and replace a value of dictionary key

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a python script that will read a python file and then search and replace a value of a dictionary key.
For example, I have a file name config.py as below

# config.py:

```
  dict1 = {'fname': 'mann1', 'lname': 'mit1'}
  dict2 = {'std': 'second', 'class': 'abcd'}
  list = ['sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3']
  dict3 = {'fname': 'mann2', 'lname': 'mit2'}
```

---

below is a code I tried which is at all not doing as I want it to be, 
`

```
 file1 = 'config.py'
  new_value = 'newval'
  for line in fileinput.input(file1, inplace=1):
  if not line.lstrip(' ').startswith('#') and re.match(r'^dict1 =', line, re.M):
     _infile_var = str(line.split('=, |, :')[0].rstrip(' '))
     _infile_set = str(line.split('=, |, :')[1].lstrip(' ').rstrip())
     line = "%s : %s\n" % (_infile_var, newval)
  sys.stdout.write(line)
```

`

can somebody help me here how I can do it?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Show your attempt.

Comment: Is there any reason to keep config in this *.py format? Something like JSON or INI file has much better read and write methods which are easy to use.

Comment: Please add a description of how exactly your code is failing. Is there an exception? If so, provide the stack trace. Is it providing the incorrect result? If so, show it. Is it simply doing nothing? Also, double-check the indentation of the provided code.